# React-Router is refreshing page when I follow a route using <a> tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm building a React app that has links pointing to predefined routes.

```
<a href="/my/react/route/">Click Here</a>
```

The routes resolve fine, but it's refreshing the page, thereby slowing down app performance. How do I avoid re-rendering the entire page?

Comment: `Link` eventually calls `history.pushState` which is what sets the URL without causing the page to refresh. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Fix the problem by using the `<Link>` tag included with react-router.

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export class ToolTip extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Link to="/My/Route">Click Here</Link>
    )
  }
};
```

Comment: Does this hold true for static site generation as well?

Comment: How about NavItem href in react-bootstrap?

<Nav bsStyle="tabs">
                  <NavItem  href="/plan">
                  </NavItem>
</Nav>

Comment: NavItem acts like a <a href..> so it will reload the page

Comment: Does this mean using `a href` is discouraged altogether for a React SPA, and always replace with `link` when making basic links?  e.g. `a href` causes full reload in all cases?

Answer (score 5):

You need to:

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"
```

then import the component you wish to go to

```
import Example from "./component/Example"
```

Then use Link like this

```
<Link to="/Example">
   <h4>Example Page</h4>
</Link>
```

This will stop the refreshing.

Note that, if `to="/Example"` matches a route you've specified in your `BrowserRouter` and then it sends you there.

Learn more here [Reat Training / React Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic)

Answer (score 4):

First answer was correct but I didn't found Link from react-router-dom. It was in my case here:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router';
```

Comment: Different versions of react-router:


`version 4: import { Link } from react-router-dom`
`version 3 or before: import { Link } from react-router`

Comment: it is not available in earlier version but with version 4 and above you can do this `import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'`

Answer (score 1):

Hi semantic ui react example

```
             <Menu.Item name="NotFound" as={NavLink} to="/dadsadsa" />
```

Comment: This is the correct answer if using React-Bootstrap [Nav.Link](https://react-bootstrap-v4.netlify.app/components/navs/#nav-link-props). Import `NavLink` from react-router-dom. Change `href` to `to` and add the `as` property: `<Nav.Link to={"/admin/account/" + business.id} as={NavLink}>Account</Nav.Link>`

Comment: Hi @mcarson your answer is correct thank you

Answer (score 0):

In case the above methods don't work, check if you are importing the right component where you are defining the routes. (In my case, I imported a component with the same name but from a wrong path)